# MS ACCESS The specified field [XXXXX} could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM

Tags: ms-access

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a Query in MS ACCESS. 
The specified field "[XXXX}" could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM Clause of your SQL Statement.

Not sure how to go about this error in MS Access. I'm very new in MS Access.

```
SELECT Round([Revenue Amount]/[Quantity],2) AS [Rate Paid]
FROM ([Profit Report] RIGHT JOIN ([HBMA 001] INNER JOIN [Key Report] ON [HBMA 001].ID = [Key Report].ID) 
ON ([Profit Report].[S Number] = [Key Report].[S Number]) AND 
([Profit Report].[SL Number] = [Key Report].[SL Number])) 
LEFT JOIN [LTB Analysis] ON [Key Report].[LTB Number] = [HHB LTB Analysis].[LTB Number]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error description is quite clear: you certainly have 2 (or more) tables with identical field names:  [Revenue Amount] and/or  [Quantity]. Just fix that by prefixing the field name by the table name.
e.g:

```
SELECT Round([sometable].[Revenue Amount]/[someOtherTable].[Quantity],2) AS [Rate Paid]
```

in Design view, just change
`Round([Revenue Amount]/[Quantity],2)` into
`Round([sometable].[Revenue Amount]/[someOtherTable].[Quantity],2)`
(using the right table names of course)

Comment: Hi Patrick, So, I will change the actual SQL Code and not using a MS Access function/property of some sort? Thanks

Comment: You can change that in SQL view or in Design view.

Comment: Ok, I understand and thanks. Ok, I have the tables shown as part of Design View and I dragged to the Design View Upper WIndow for establishing Relationship/Join between the three tables. So, my ignorance with MS Access is that if I Drop the Table that has the duplicate column, it drops it completely from the bottom part where the field , table, sort, show, criteria, or is showing. I need to include some of the field but not all from the table that has the duplicate columns.