# The specified field could refer to more than one table in the FROM clause of your SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Currently I am in a database class and working in Access with SQL. I have to list some objects with 2 conditions described within the `WHERE` statement however before my SQL code even executes there seems to be an error that states

> The specified field 'eventno' could refer to more than one table in the FROM clause of your SQL statement

I have no idea how to fix the error and what the error is even specifically telling me.  Would someone please help me and clarify the error for me to further my knowledge of it? Thank you.

```
SELECT planno, eventno, workdate, activity
FROM EventPlan, Facility, EventRequest
WHERE EventPlan.eventno = EventRequest.eventno
    AND EventRequest.facno = Facility.facno
    AND workdate BETWEEN #01-Dec-2013# AND #31-Dec-2013#
    AND facname = 'Basketball arena';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS ACCESS The specified field \[XXXXX} could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892084/ms-access-the-specified-field-xxxxx-could-refer-to-more-than-one-table-listed)

Answer (score 4):

First, only use commas in the `FROM` clause if you want a Cartesian product and are using MS Access.

Second, qualify all column names.

Now is the time to learn good habits.  So, I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT ep.planno, ep.eventno, ?.workdate, ?.activity
FROM (EventPlan as ep INNER JOIN
      EventRequest as er
      ON ep.eventno = er.eventno
     ) INNER JOIN
     Facility as f
     ON er.facno = f.facno
WHERE ?.workdate BETWEEN #01-Dec-2013# AND #31-Dec-2013# AND
      ?.facname = 'Basketball arena';
```

The `?`s are for the table aliases for the tables where the columns come from.  I don't know your data model, but you do, so you can fill them in.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the field `eventno` exists in multiple tables, but in the `SELECT` clause, you didn't specify from which table to get the value.

Change your SQL to something like this:

```
SELECT planno, EventPlan.eventno, workdate, activity
FROM EventPlan, Facility, EventRequest
WHERE EventPlan.eventno = EventRequest.eventno
    AND EventRequest.facno = Facility.facno
    AND workdate BETWEEN #01-Dec-2013# AND #31-Dec-2013#
    AND facname = 'Basketball arena';
```

Also, it would be good to specify your join conditions in the `FROM` clause of your query, instead of in the filter (`WHERE` clause), like this:

```
SELECT planno, EventPlan.eventno, workdate, activity
FROM EventPlan
    LEFT JOIN Facility ON EventPlan.facno = Facility.facno
    LEFT JOIN EventRequest ON EventPlan.eventno = EventRequest.eventno
WHERE workdate BETWEEN #01-Dec-2013# AND #31-Dec-2013#
    AND facname = 'Basketball arena';
```